# Automatically forward ports from clients

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, port, router

My system has a server and multiple clients. the server has a service for the clients and each client has a service too, for talking to other clients.

I forward the server's service port manually on the router but the future client can not do it by him self after the installation.

Is there a way to automatically forward ports by code from the client side through the installation?

**My main question is** - Does this approach is wise? Should the system needs to be build deferentially?

Project details:

1. **C# - WCF, Communication - NetTcpBinding**.
2. The server is on my computer (Home network). Server's service port : 8080.
3. The clients can be installed everywhere. Client's service port: 8081.

*I'm not known with the IIS technology, can it help in this scenario?

Comment: It is really unclear which port you want to forward, but I'm gonna go ahead and say "no, you probably can't". Perhaps if you add more detail about which server and which client get installed where, how they are supposed to talk to each other and where exactly you'd like to add a port forwarding rule.

Comment: Im using net tcp binding + updated post @CodeCaster.

Comment: Still not clear which port you want to forward and why.

Comment: I want to forward port 8081 on each client's router so the client be able to host a service to other clients @CodeCaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you're describing sounds like a **mesh** network, generally you do not want clients to forward ports, be it automatically or not.

If it's absolutely necessary you could implement [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), there is an elaborate article [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP) describing how to do so in .NET with a library. Note that you will have to select a different port.

I would strongly recommend to go for a different option though, having the server manage connections between clients is more managable and safer. There are very few valid arguments in favor of a model where a server is present and clients omit it at times:

- Bandwidth, the server might not be able to handle all the data with reasonable throughput (i.e. torrent)
- Security, the server might be only there for client updates (i.e. P2P chatclient with updater)

From the sound of it, your project does not apply to either.

EDIT: Because you have indicated the project is basically a torrent client, I would recommend reading up on the UPnP article.

Comment: Im building a torrent so the client must download from other clients so a service to each client is require. Dont you agree @Chavez ? Btw, what is mesh network?

Comment: In short, a star model is where clients A, B and C connect to server Z. A mesh model is where client A connects to B and C, B connects to A and C, C connects to B and A. I've updated my answer and I notice your project does apply to one of the exceptions where this is favorable. In that case I would recommend reading up on the UPnP article I linked.

Comment: Does UPnP support WCF? (My torrent is already build  with nettcpbinding). @Chavez

Comment: Read the article, you will find that UPnP is a service standard on routers that enables programs and services to forward ports by themselves.